# React Native Navigation Syntax

Tags: react-native, navigation

What is the difference between using `navigation.navigate()` and `navigation.dispatch(CommonAction.navigate())` in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs explanation is:

> The dispatch method lets us send a navigation action object which determines how the navigation state will be updated. All of the navigation functions like navigate use dispatch behind the scenes.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dispatch

AFAIK there is no real difference between using actions and navigate